# TitleStyle Gauges Nativescript

Tags: styles, nativescript

I am new to nativescript and the use of their gauges. I want to change the styling inside the gauges. The only thing I can find I can use is titleStyle but nowhere is described how I need to use it. So my question is how do I use it.[Here is an example of how I have it now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hujtb.png) In the picture is how I have it now but I want the title bigger and a different color.

Already much thanks for your help!][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CNxr.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like gauge styling is done with the [ScaleStyle](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/api/classes/scalestyle.html) property. There are some examples of how to set ScaleStyle properties in your view [here](https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-samples/blob/release/sdk/app/gauges/customization/customization.xml#L8). Some of those properties apply specifically to the label(s).